# Balls in differently shaped boxes

Tags: geometry

Here's a question that occurred to me about 20 years ago.  I had bought a basketball which was packaged in a cube-shaped box just big enough for it, i.e. the ball touched each of the six sides of the box at one small point.  I then wondered whether, had the box been a regular tetrahedron instead, the volume of the box could have been smaller.  I could visualize with some confidence that the tetrahedron would indeed need less volume, but I couldn't do the math, and I don't think I could learn the math, so I don't know how much less volume it would need. I pictured that perhaps if the balls were put in tetrahedrons and stacked alternately vertex-up and vertex-down more could be put in a display.  Thanks to someone who could do the math.

Comment: Regular tetrahedron side a has vol $a^3/{\sqrt{24}}$ and inradius $r=a/{\sqrt{24}}$, so vol is $24r^3$. Cube has vol $8r^3$. So the vol of the tetrahedron is 3 times bigger. That is not surprising if you think about it - there is far more "wasted" space inside the tetrahedron.

Comment: Your answer jogged me to look for drawings of what I had visualized, and I realize now just how off my imagination was!  Although my question will be rated negatively, I'm glad I asked it, for now I'm relieved a misconception.

Comment: Did you consider packing your basketball into a  regular dodecahedron or Icosahedron? In terms of stacking, then you may be able to save space.

Comment: Some more formatting would be nice. This is a wall of text.